# sinonjs : Attempted to wrap which is already wrapped

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, sinon, sinon-chai

I know this has been asked multiple times. I read through answers yet I wasn't able to solve this. My case seems to be a bit different because I am using Cucumber 2.3.x and sinon 1.17.7 (fairly old stack)

Cucumber feature:

```
    Background:
        Given list of documents

    Scenario: Create packs for gMethod
        Given I have 200 from Service and do not call CMethod
        When I request pack creation for splits with new contract
        Then packs will be created with packId as per new contract
```

My Tests:

```
   Before(function (fixtures, callback) {
       gStub = sinon.stub(featureFlag, 'gMethod');
       gStub.returns(false)
       callback();
   });


   After(function (fixtures, callback) {
       featureFlag.gMethod.restore(); //tried gStub.restore as well but that didn't solve either
       callback();
   });
```

Even after restoring the stubbed method, I get the  "Attempted to wrap gMethod which is already wrapped:

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Post the full stack trace. If you can, create a runnable reproduction on RunKit. Which line is throwing the error? I do not know Cucumber (for JS): is the Before/After executed once per test suite or once for every testcase?